# Dependent Combo-box in LWC

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, lightning-combobox

I have a combo-box in LWC - whose values get populated on load of the page with the help of `@wire`. The code is as follows:

```
@wire(fetchL1ProductValues,{userType:'$userType',accountId:'$recordId'})
productList;

get productOptions(){
    console.log('>>>>'+JSON.stringify(this.productList.data));
    return this.productList.data;
}
                    <lightning-combobox
                        class="l1ProductCmp"
                        value={l1SelectedValue}
                        placeholder="-Select-"
                        options={productOptions}
                        onchange={onSelectProductL1} >
                    </lightning-combobox>

   onSelectProductL1(event){
   this.l1product = event.target.value;
    fetchL2ProductValues({productId: this.l1product ,userType: 
           this.userType})
    .then(result => {
      //how to transform the result so that i can populate another combo-box with this result
  }
```

The issue I'm facing here is that I am not able to populate the second combo-box with the result which i have obtained in `onSelectProductL1` function. Imperative method of calling apex is not working in this scenario. we cannot use `@wire` inside a function. What would be the ideal solution to this problem?

Comment: is `fetchL2ProductValues` a custom apex method? Do you want to execute and get the result on change of the combo box?

Comment: Yes it is a custom apex method..which i want to execute & get the result.

Comment: This link has the solution to this problem. https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/268353/fire-wire-on-an-event-change-lwc/268364#268364

Answer (score 1):

I think you might want to make use of a second @wire function similar to this using dynamic/reactive variables.

```
@wire(fetchL1ProductValues,{userType:'$userType',accountId:'$recordId'})
productList;

@wire(fetchL2ProductValues, {userType: '$userType', productId: '$l1productId'})
secondProductList;

@track l1productId;

onSelectProductL1(event) {
  this.l1productId = event.target.value;
}
```

When `l1ProductId` changes, the `fetchL2ProductValues` method should run and update `secondProductList`. See "Wire an Apex Method with a Dynamic Parameter" [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.apex)

Comment: On change of l1ProductId , fetchL2ProductValues is not firing again to get the updated values. Do u have a working example for this??

Comment: This link has the solution to this issue.
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/268353/fire-wire-on-an-event-change-lwc/268364#268364