# Parse JSON in LWC

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components

I'm getting a JSON response as follows :-

`tthis.selectedRecord {"Id":"01t5C000002xxx","Name":"xxxES"}`,wanted to know how do i get the value of ID & Name separately.

Comment: What have you tried? Being that JSON stands for _JavaScript_ Object Notation, and  the controller for LWC is, in fact, JavaScript...there shouldn't be any parsing required. Just use it as you would any other JavaScript object...

Comment: I tried JSON.stringify(this.selectedRecord) - which is giving me the value of ID & Name {"Id":"01t5C000002xxx","Name":"xxxES"}. I want the value of the Id so that i can save this record as a look up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on your comment, it sounds like you already have a native JavaScript object; no parsing is required:

```
console.log(this.selectedRecord.Id);
console.log(this.selectedRecord.Name);
```

Make sure you pay attention to the capitalization of the variables; `Name` is different than `name`.

Comment: Thanks sfdcfox..guess i complicated it alot :). I have one more issue..could you help me on https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/265900/dependent-combo-box-in-lwc?noredirect=1#comment402318_265900