# fire @wire on an event change LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-design-system, lightning-combobox

I have a picklist in a combo-box, on change of the picklist value @ wire method should fire is it possible or what is the work around??. As per the below example when this.l1productId value changes in the on change event method,@wire(fetchL2ProductValues) should fire.

```
       @wire(fetchL1ProductValues, 
      {userType:'$userType',accountId:'$recordId'})
       productList;

     @wire(fetchL2ProductValues, {userType: '$userType', productId: 
    '$l1productId'})
     secondProductList;

    @track l1productId;

   onSelectProductL1(event) {
      this.l1productId = event.target.value;
    }
```

Comment: Your code is supposed to work. The `l1productId` update is already detected by the call of your `fetchL2ProductValues` method. What isn't working?

Comment: I put debug logs to check if my apex code is getting called..but i don't see the debug logs in my method where i return l2 value's based on productl1

Comment: Could it be because of the cache? Do you change with values you never chose before?

Comment: Yes i changed the values..put alerts & confirmed that values got changed. But i feel @wire works fine only 'ON LOAD'.

Comment: whats the type of the userType variable? I think @wire service only work with primitive data type as parameters.

Comment: user type is a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to call refreshApex from the @salesforce/apex which refreshes the cache.

You can find example and documentation [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/apex)

Comment: Tried the same..but l1selectedValue is still holding the value it got populated while page load.  
onSelectProductL1(event){
         alert('before change '+this.l1SavedValue );
        this.l1SavedValue = event.target.value;
         alert('after change '+this.l1SavedValue);
        alert('before refresh apex');
        refreshApex(this.l2ProductList);
    }

@wire(fetchL2ProductValues,{productId: '$l1SavedValue',userType: '$userType'})
    l2ProductList;

Comment: Thanks for the help.I resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this by using refreshApex.I was setting the value for this.l1SavedValue in JS onload method "renderedCallback". Every time on change event fired, onload event used to get called & it used to reset the value back to onload value. Hence i used the following code in renderedCallback. By using If we prevent onload method to reset the value of this.l1SavedValue for subsequent changes.

```
 if(this.l1SavedValue === undefined){
        this.l1SavedValue = result.Product_L1__c;
 }

 @wire(fetchL2ProductValues,{productId: '$l1SavedValue',userType: '$userType'}) 
 l2ProductList;

  onSelectProductL1(event){ 
  this.l1SavedValue = event.target.value; 
  refreshApex(this.l2ProductList);
  }
```